# Is calling java.lang.Object constructor really necessary?

Tags: java

I've recently installed bytecode outline Eclipse plugin and discovered that my Test class

```
public class Test {
}
```

calls java.lang.Object's constructor

```
public class Test {
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 15 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init>()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this LTest; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

`INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init>()`V means calling java.lang.Object's constructor

Does it make any sense? Judging by java.lang.Object bytecode

```
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 37 L0
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 0
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

it's doing nothing.  Just returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to in order to satisfy [section 4.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.2) of the JVM specification on structural constraints:

> Each instance initialization method (§2.9), except for the instance initialization method derived from the constructor of class Object, must call either another instance initialization method of this or an instance initialization method of its direct superclass super before its instance members are accessed.

Now the rule *could* be relaxed for classes which are direct subclasses of `Object` - but I doubt that it would have any benefit, and would be inelegant (IMO). What if the `Object` constructor *did* perform some initialization in the future? Would you really want a spec which allowed you to bypass it?

Comment: right, spec says so, but because of this wise spec any class we create has a dozen of useless bytes in it

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev: Well, any class derived directly from `Object`. Yup. So every 10,000 such classes will take up a staggering 120K of extra space. Yikes! Seriously, do you think that is significant, even slightly?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev: Not really. That way madness lies - you'll spend your life micro-optimizing every byte, taking time which would be far better spent analyzing *real* bottlenecks and changing bigger architecture decisions. There's a cost/benefit balance here - and the cost in terms of inconsistency is really high, IMO. You're basically saying it would be okay to *require* that the `Object` constructor didn't do anything, on every JVM, ever, whether acting under a debugger, profiler etc or not. That's way too high a cost to eliminate 12 bytes per class.

Answer (score 3):

Java compiler should not treat `java.lang.Object` differently than any other base class that probably has more sophisticated default constructor. Therefore the constructor of base class must be executed from constructor of any subclass. This byte code is also safe for future modifications of base class (including `Object`): if one day somebody changes base class the code of subclass should not be re-compiled.

BTW changes in base class including Object are not so exotic: think about instrumentation packages. If you want to instrument the JDK and for example count all created object you want to modify byte code of `java.lang.Object`. Now, if byte code does not contain invocation of `Object` constructor your instrumented code just will not run.